# parse the body of an eml file in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

My ultimate goal is to open an eml file in Excel vba and end up with the body of the message in a string that I can then use to search for different parameters.  I've found a solution using MailItem and an Outlook application, however the machine I'm working on errors out when running this code:

```
Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set x = MyOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Outlook 2013 opens, but then gives me an error message saying OLMAPI32.dll and then crashes.  Eventually, I receive error 429 "ActiveX component can't create object."

I would like either a solution to this error or a workaround way to get the body of an eml file into a string.  I've been successful at getting the subject of the email by using this code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "^Subject:"
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
   Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)
   If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
       Cells(i, n) = strSearchString
       i = i + 1
       Exit Do
   End If
Loop
```

However, from examining a few random eml files, it doesn't appear like there is a way to flag the body of the text like I can with the subject.

Disregard the i and n, its not really relevant for this question.  I'm just placing the subject in a cell determined elsewhere.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How would you use Outlook Object Model to open an EML file? So what you really need is a MIME parser, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .Body function?  [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151) article may help.

Note that this code is performed inside of Outlook, not Excel.

```
Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem) Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.Namespace Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem Dim strFileName As String

'~~> Excel Variables
Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
Dim lRow As Long

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

'~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

'~~> If not found then create new instance
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Show Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open the relevant file
Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xls")

'~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'~~> Write to outlook
With oXLws
    '
    '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
    '~~> For example
    '
    .Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Subject
    .Range("B" & lRow).Value = olMail.SenderName
    .Range("C" & lRow).Value = olMail.Body
    '.Range("C" & lRow).Value = olMail.HTMLBody 
    '
End With

'~~> Close and Clean up Excel
oXLwb.Close (True)
oXLApp.Quit
Set oXLws = Nothing
Set oXLwb = Nothing
Set oXLApp = Nothing

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```